# oracle primary_key and foreign_key

Tags: oracle, primary-key, foreign-keys

Is it possible to maintain relationship between two tables without primary key and foreign key

if it is possible then how?

Comment: The $64K question: Why would you want to?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In a multi-user environment, you won't be able to maintain integrity (no orphan for example) without either foreign keys or a full TABLE LOCK on the child table. In other words, without foreign keys, you can't have both integrity and concurrency.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, but it is highly inadvisable to do so.  Any other solution you adopt will either perform less well, or be unreliable, or both.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you could use a unique key for the parent table, you don't necessarily need to use the primary key :)

< /facetiousness >